# Clustering credit card accounts based on their balance trajectories

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am trying to cluster credit accounts based on the shape of their balance trajectories over the next 36 months, to identify the different types of shapes possible in the portfolio. Here is how I am doing it:

1. Standardize balance trajectories by converting them into proportion of balances (balance at each point in time divided by the initial balance at the starting point)
2. Do PCA and reduce from 36 to 3 dimensions. The top 3 components explain almost ~85% of the variations in the initial 36 values.
3. Do K-means clustering (using fastclus in SAS).

The issue is that the CCC (cubic clustering criterion) value I end up with is very high (~-500) even after I identify almost 15-20% of my data as outliers (using the strict= options in fastclus). I understand the CCC value should be around 2-3 for a statistically sound clustering. Is there any way I can improve this? Should i normalize the 3 principal components before doing k-means?

*Update: It seems PCA can lead to order loss because it is not mindful of the sequence in which balances occur. Can anyone suggest better parameters to capture 36 months of balance information that I can use in K-means? I want to do K-means with lowest dimensionality possible because distance doesn't work with high dimensional data (36 in my case). I think using slope, curvature and level. I can define level with average values, slope with regression slope coefficient of balance versus time equation but how do I define curvature?*

My basic goal is to cluster those accounts together which have a similar balance trajectory.

Comment: Why use PCA at all? It does not get more meaningful/interpretable if you stack more stuff.

Comment: The other option is to calculate distances between two accounts based on the value of their balance ratio at each of the 36 points in the trajectory. That makes the trajectories more volatile. I am using PCA so that each cluster captures the rough shape of each trajectory.

Comment: Define "volatile". Why is this worse? You want "trajectories", so why destroy them with PCA that doesn't use order?

Comment: These are the cases when an account's balance proportion abruptly drops to 0 or shoots to a very high value for one or two periods and then goes back to the more and gradual trend which the trajectory was following till then.

Comment: And why do you think PCA handles this better? Can you prove this mathematically?

Comment: I don't have mathematical  proof but the trajectories that I get after reverse transforming top 3 components seem to follow the general trend. Can you please explain what you mean by 'order loss in PCA'?

Comment: PCA mixes all dimensions, but your dimensions have a temporal order that you may want to use. Also, your reverse transformation has additional information encoded in the protection that is *not* in the vectors you analyze. In fact, some of the important scale information.